# jquery append creates extra element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, append, innerhtml

The `jquery.append` in my code creates an extra element.  I am not sure what's wrong.

Thank you very much for your help

```
var topDiv = document.createElement('div');

this.topDiv.innerHTML = '<div class="MyDiv1"></div><div class="MyDiv2">' +
                        '<canvas class="MyCanvas" width="10" height="1">' +
                        '</canvas></div><div class="MyDiv3"></div><span class="MySpan"></span>';
MyCanvasEle = topDiv.childNodes[1].childNodes[0];
MyCanvasEle.getContext('2d');
```

I want to add another `div` to MyDiv2, same level as MyCanvas. Eventually I will replace 0 (zero) with i in a for loop, but for now, the first append gives me the element with the desired location, width, and len, but it also gives me extra element with no properties.

```
$(".MyDiv2" ).append('<div id="MyID' + 0 + '" class="MyClass1"><table border="1" width="100% height="5"><tr><td></td></tr></table></div>');
$("#MyID"+0).css("top", 5);
```

Comment: The append is missing a second "+" after `+ 0`. I assume that is just a typo, but best fix that first :)

Comment: Yes, it's a typo in the question.  Typo fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming the `0` will be replaced with a variable, in any case your append code is invalid - you are missing a `+`:

```
                                           V - insert here :)
$(".MyDiv2" ).append('<div id = "MyID' + 0 + '" class="MyClass1"><table border="1" width="100% height="5"><tr><td></td></tr></table></div>');
$("#MyID"+0).css("top", 5);
```

For neatness also get rid of the spaces around your `id =`:

```
$(".MyDiv2" ).append('<div id="MyID' + 0 + '" class="MyClass1"><table border="1" width="100% height="5"><tr><td></td></tr></table></div>');
$("#MyID"+0).css("top", 5);
```

*Always a good idea to use a debugger (like the F12 Chrome features) to a) examine your HTML structure and b) breakpoint your code.*

Comment: Removed the extra spaces. Thanks for your suggestion. I'll start learning how to use breakpoint in Firebug.